# How to order by more than one field in Grails?

Tags: grails, sql-order-by, grails-orm

Is there a way to get a list ordered by two fields, say last and first names?

I know `.listOrderByLastAndFirst` and `.list(sort:'last, first')` won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This old solution no longer works. Please see mattlary's answer below**

You may have to write a custom finder in HQL or use the Criteria Builder.

```
MyDomain.find("from Domain as d order by last,first desc")
```

Or

```
def c = MyDomain.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
       order("last,first", "desc")
}
```

Comment: Not sure why it has been marked negative but the first approach Mydomain.find definitely works. probably he has some typo in the above but that is no reason for minus. +1 from me.

Comment: Worked 5 years ago ;) Shame I can't delete it.

Comment: Oh how I dislike people downvoting something that used to work.

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: last,first of: MyDomain
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1616)

Answer (score 83):

[Hates_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326152/2521769) criteria answer didn't seem to work for me; putting `"last,first"` in order will only cause exceptions saying, `"Property 'last,first' not found"`.  To order on two fields, you can do the following:

```
def c = MyDomain.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    and{
       order('last','desc')
       order('first','desc')
    }
}
```

Comment: is the 'and' block necessary here?

Comment: @Matt Lachman: Interesting, I thought there was an implicit `and` around a criteria. Can you explain what happens without the `and`?

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit too hasty. I retract my comment: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Criteria-Restrictions-question-AND-or-OR-td1351000.html

Comment: It works the same without the outer `and` block in Grails 2.3.7

Answer (score 11):

This is quite old but helped me in finding a suitable solution. A "cleaner" code example by using withCriteria shortcut:

```
def c = MyDomain.withCriteria {
    and {
        order('last', 'desc')
        order('first', 'desc')
    }
}
```

Comment: So far, this is definitely the cleanest solution. I don't expect we can do any better.

Answer (score 6):

```
MyDomain.findAll(sort: ['first': 'desc','last':'desc'])
```

works with grails-datastore-gorm:6.0.3

Comment: This solution worked for me with Grails 4.0.3 and GORM 7.0.4. You can also do something like `Person.findByUsername(username, [sort: ['lastName': 'asc', 'firstName': 'asc']])`

Answer (score 5):

More complicated ordering criteria, (tested in Grails 2.1.0)

```
def c = MyDomain.withCriteria {
    property {
        order('last', 'desc')
    }
    order('first', 'desc')
}
```

sorts first by MyDomain.property.last then by MyDomain.first

Answer (score 5):

you can do this

```
def results=MyDomain.findAll([sort:"last",order:'desc'],[sort:"first",order:'desc']);
```

this line of code will first sort results from domain class "MyDomain" first by last name and then by first name of the person .

Answer (score 4):

I think a criteria is the best bet, but you did the right thing by attempting a finder first.  When retrieving domain objects from GORM, the right order to make the attempt is: dynamic finder, criteria, HQL.

Answer (score 4):

This query is working on the basis of first field. When the first field is blank then it is shorted by the second field.

```
order('last','desc')
order('first','desc')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were sorting lists on the contents of their items, you would need to implement a comparator which would have some smarts to enable to you decide the sort order based on multiple properties.

Some examples of Groovy-style comparators are shown [here](http://devambling.taragin.com/2008/11/groovy-sort-follow-up_05.html)

However if the list you are sorting is being returned from a database query, you would be better off sorting it using a CrteriaQuery and sorts on that

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem.
Since my list is not so big, I use groovy sort, as I want to sort on fields of linked domain:
CalendarData -> Attraction

```
def listCalendar (Calendar calendar) {
    respond CalendarData.where {
        calendar == calendar
    }.list().sort{ "$it.attraction.type?:' '$it.attraction.name" }
}
```