# Grails - Sort by two fields in a query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I Have Such a domain class in my project:

```
class Log  {

Integer entityId
Integer tableId
Date logDt
}
```

I would like to select all the records by a certain tableId, and sort them by entityId **and** logDt desc.
Sorting by one filed works fine:

```
Log.findAllByTableId(tableID, [sort: 'entityId', order: 'desc'])
```

but when I try to sort by both fields:

`Log.findAllByTableId(tableID, [sort: 'entityId,logDt', order: 'desc'])`

I get an error that there is no such field `'entityId,logDt'` at this table.

What is the right syntax to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to order by more than one field in Grails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326053/how-to-order-by-more-than-one-field-in-grails)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the dynamic finders, you just can sort by one property.

If you would like to sort by multiple properties you could use a criteria or a HQL query.

Here is an example using a criteria:

```
def logs = Log.createCriteria().list {
    eq('tableId', tableID)
    order('entityId', 'desc')
    order('logDt', 'desc')
}
```

Comment: I have got my answere from the question cause i have one parameters

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
Log.findAllByTableId(tableID, [sort: ['entityId': 'desc', 'logDt': 'desc']])
```

It works, with Grails 3.1.9 onwards.

NB: Probably, works with some previous versions too, never tried though.