# Grails namedQuery sort order by multiple columns

Tags: grails

Given a namedQuery:

```
class MyDomainObject {

    String someProperty

    static namedQueries = {

        myNamedQuery {
            // some implementation here
        }

    }
}
```

I can use it to generate a list, sorted by a single key, like this ([documentation for 2.4.3 here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html)):

```
def resultsList = MyDomainObject.myNamedQuery.list(sort: "someProperty", order: "desc")
```

How do I order the results by multiple columns?  I'd like to be able to define the sort parameters dynamically, not define them in the query.

Comment: I see here [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) that named queries support the criteria builder syntax. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326053/how-to-order-by-more-than-one-field-in-grails) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332369/grails-sort-by-two-fields-in-a-query).

Comment: @DaddyPumpkin those seem to incorporate the sort parameters into the named query.  I want to execute the sorting to be independent of the named query.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882992/grails-mapping-sort-on-multiple-fields-groovy-sort-on-multiple-map-entries) is what you need then.

Comment: I can see what you're trying to do there, but it's not the same thing as what I need.  The query is executed within the (remote) database, whereas the list.sort() executes on the Grails server.  They're not the same machine.  I think I've got the basis of a solution which I'm trying to get working - it involves concatenating queries and then calling list().

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way, but I ended up creating another named query that I can concatenate onto my chosen one (I could always incorporate into the original query too).

```
// expects to be passed a List containing a series of Maps
orderByMultipleColumns { List columnsToSortBy ->
    columnsToSortBy.each { Map field ->
        order("${field.fieldName}", field.fieldOrder)
    }
}

// usage:
List orderByList = []
    // ...
    // within some loop that I use:
    orderByList << [fieldName: someValue, fieldOrder: dir] // dir == 'asc' or 'desc'
    // ...

MyDomainObject.myNamedQuery().orderByMultipleColumns(orderList).listDistinct(max: length, offset: start)
```